# Let $G$ be a group, and $M$, $N$ be normal subgroups such that $M \leq N$. If $G/N \cong G/M$ then need it be true that $N = M$?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

Let $G$ be a group, and $M$, $N$ be normal subgroups such that $M \leq N$. Suppose that $G/N \cong G/M$, then need it be true that $N = M$? My gut instinct is yes, but unsure how to go about showing this.

I am aware that without the stipulation that $M \leq N$, the statement does not hold. I believe I have seen this statement used (without justification) in a paper and I'm just having trouble justifying it myself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not change questions once they have an answer. Instead, ask it as a new question.

Comment: [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1940964/when-is-a-group-isomorphic-to-a-non-trivial-quotient-group-of-itself) has some answers to your question

Comment: Right, thank you. I'll undo the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not true. Take $G=\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\times\cdots$ (a countable product), $N=\mathbb Z\times\{0\}\times\{0\}\times\cdots$ and $M$ the trivial subgroup.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, thank you. What if we add the constraint that $G$ itself is finitely presentable? (I will edit my question to add this)

Comment: Do you mean that you are going to edit your question in such a way that my answer doesn't make sense anymore?

Comment: Not at all, see the edit above.